# AJAX Load scafolded MVC 4 partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, dialog

I have created a partial view(MVC4) using scaffolding option for create operation.I am just trying to load that into the jquery ui Dialog.I can able to load the partial view.but while loading I lost all the validation which MVC 4 generated for me.

Is it possible to load the partial view(Scaffolded) to the jquery dialog?

Here is the code i have used for the pop up

```
$(function () {
    $("#CreateDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Create": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        dialogClass: "no-title",
        hide: {
            effect: "scale",
            easing: "easeInBack"
        },
        show: {
            effect: "scale",
            easing: "easeOutBack"
        }
    });
});

function openModalPopUp() {

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Expense/CreatePartial',
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        $('#CreateDialog').html(result);
    }
});

$("#CreateDialog").dialog("open");
```

}

and my MODEL(Sample) :

```
@model EFMvcWebRole.Models.ExpenseEntity

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ExpenseEntity</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ECValue)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ECValue)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ECValue)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Category)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TotalSalary)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalSalary)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TotalSalary)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Remaining)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Remaining)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Remaining)
        </div>

    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Are you submitting the form using submit button or sending the data using ajax in onclick event of any button.
kindly show me your submitting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Include JS files i.e `Jquery Unobtrusive js` file in your Partial View also then it work fine ,some times this problem comes in partial view in asp.net mvc(because form is dynamically added to the DOM).

Just include this js file in your Partial View also :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

------------------OR try this in Partial View--------------------------

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("form"));
```

Comment: @Hsakarp..i think above answer will solve your problem if need more help then comment..thanks..

Comment: yeah, i am testing that, will post that soon . Thanks